# What about a lower and an upper bound of $\log |\sin N_n|$, where $N_n$ is the primorial of order $n$?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, supremum-and-infimum

While I was playing with the product representation for the function $$\frac{\sin x}{x}$$
and the Nicolas equivalence to the Riemann hypothesis, I wondered if it is possible to find unconditionally some upper and lower bound for the sequence $$\log|\sin N_n|\tag{1}$$
for integers $n\geq 1$, where $N_n=\prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ is the primorial of order $n$ (this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html)), thus here $p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime number.

> **Question.** Is it known or can you compute any (not obvious) lower and upper bounds of our sequence $$\text{lower bound}<\log|\sin N_n|<\text{upper bound}\tag{2}$$
>   for  the segment, say us $1\leq n\leq 100$? **Many thanks.**

I've calculated some terms, and I believe that the question has mathematical meaning. If it is in the literature please answer this as a reference request.

Comment: Everyone if isn't possible do anything please add a comment. Many thanks.

Comment: Your question would be improved if you could add some evidence that it is answerable. For example, are there similar quantities involving the primorial for which explicit bounds are known? Are there any known methods you feel could answer your question that you are having trouble applying?

Comment: Many thanks I am agree with the spirit your questions @AntonioVargas 
I have many doubts about if my Question is reasonable.